# Unable to Resolve Deprecation of UIWebView warning while uploading Xamarin application

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, uiwebview, deprecation-warning

I Have followed the blog https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/uiwebview-deprecation-xamarin-forms/ to remove the UIWebView dependency in my project.

According to the document

1)xamarin.forms version is 4.6
2)xamarin.ios version is 13.20
3)I added the command in mtouch Arguments and linker is link All

I still got warning while upoading build to test flight

I then followed this document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/release-notes/13/13.16#help-with-uiwebview-deprecation where we can find out whether UIWebView is still being used in our application.I am getting below in the build output.

```
MTOUCH : warning MT1502: One or more reference(s) to type 'UIKit.UIWebView' already exists inside 'Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' before linking
```

I am not sure why there is reference in Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS as xamarin package is updated to 4.6 as per the blog.

Can anyone please help me to get rid of this warning?

Comment: I had the same issue i tried all at last i just deleted obj and bin folder and re-build the project and it was success. also i suggest you to use latest xamarin.forms or at at least **4.7** it'll also help and then try to run again the command in your project `--warn-on-type-ref=UIKit.UIWebView` now see if there is any other refference. if no refference then try to upload again.

Comment: I tried deleting obj and bin folders.This still gave me warning.But My xamarin.forms version is 4.6. I'll try upgrading to 4.7

Comment: Which reference are appearing if you run `--warn-on-type-ref=UIKit.UIWebView` command?

Comment: It's giving me "MTOUCH : warning MT1502: One or more reference(s) to type 'UIKit.UIWebView' already exists inside 'Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' before linking" same warning I am getting repetitively around 4 times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your suggestions. Below is what worked for me.

1. Follow the 3 steps mentioned in
   https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/uiwebview-deprecation-xamarin-forms/
2. Run `grep -r UIWebview .` on repository level. It will show the list of    references in .sln and third party packages
3. Remove or update third party libraries. Igore bin and obj folders

For Me, I had to

1.Remove deprecated scanbot.xamarin.ios SDK and add scanbot.xamarin pkg

2.Remove hockey app SDK as it was deprecated and didn’t have any updates

3.Remove googleanalytics SDK as it wasn’t being used in the project

Comment: You can mark this answer later which will help more people with same problem:).

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this [link](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/uiwebview-deprecation-xamarin-forms/)

simply go to your iOS project, open the project properties and add this flag in the
'additional mtouch arguments field: --optimize=experimental-xforms-product-type' in your

Comment: I did refer the link and added the flag in mtouch. Still I get warning when I try to upload the App to testflight

Answer (score 0):

Use WKWebView instead of UIWebView. UIWebView has been deprecated and Now The App Store will no longer accept new apps using UIWebView as of April 2020.

```
using System.IO;
using CustomRenderer;
using CustomRenderer.iOS;
using Foundation;
using UIKit;
using WebKit;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomWebView), typeof(WebViewRender_iOS))]
namespace CustomRenderer.iOS
{
    public class WebViewRender_iOS : WkWebViewRenderer
    {
        WKUserContentController userController;
  

    protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (e.OldElement != null)
        {
            userController.RemoveAllUserScripts();
            userController.RemoveScriptMessageHandler("invokeAction");
            CustomWebView hybridWebView = e.OldElement as CustomWebView;
            hybridWebView.Cleanup();
        }

        if (e.NewElement != null)
        {
            CustomWebView hybridWebView = e.NewElement as CustomWebView;

            LoadRequest(new NSUrlRequest(new NSUrl(hybridWebView._WebURI)));
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: We are using WKWebView and it's renderer in our project and there is no way where we are directly using UIWebView in our project. So to identify if any other third party library is referencing, xamarin document suggests to use --warn-on-type-ref=UIKit.UIWebView. When I did that I got MTOUCH : warning MT1502: One or more reference(s) to type 'UIKit.UIWebView' already exists inside 'Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' before linking .So I am confused even after updating the xamarin.forms, does it still have reference to UIWebView internally

Comment: @Arpitha you can check above code which a renderer in iOS. Just put the code in your project and its working fine. Thank you let me know if you have any issue.

Comment: In our code we have implemented similar to above code. We don't have customwebview class instead we do like this [assembly: Xamarin.Forms.ExportRenderer(typeof(Xamarin.Forms.WebView), typeof(Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.CustomWkWebViewRenderer))]. Will this result in error?

Comment: yes you have to create a one class like customwebview. This class will be accessible anywhere  in xamarin shared files.

you can connect with me by skype: kamleshhbti

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different changes that need to be made for the deprecation warning to go away.

- The build configuration used to upload to the store (Release|iPhone, App Store|iPhone, etc.) in iOS Build section needs the following additional mtouch arguments `--optimize=experimental-xforms-product-type`
- The app needs to use Xamarin.Forms version >= 4.5 or >= 4.6 if using Material Visual
- It also needs to be using Xamarin.iOS 13.10.0.17 or higher, which is included with Visual Studio for Mac 8.4.1 and Visual Studio 16.4.3.
- Remove all references to `UIWebView` in the codebase

More info is included in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/webview?tabs=windows#uiwebview-deprecation-and-app-store-rejection-itms-90809) and if that doesn't resolve the issue the app may be using a third-party library with a reference to `UIWebView` that either needs updating to a version without it or removed altogether from the app.

Comment: I have followed all the steps and my codebase doesn't contain references to UIWebView. It has to do something with thirdparty libraries only. When I followed https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-to-find-and-remove-uiwebview-uses-in-your-ios-app-d9395f7baacc this document, It lead me to scanbot SDK .I have latest version of scanbot SDK, So I am reaching out to their support team

Comment: Yeah sounds like you're going to have to wait on their response since it doesn't look like the Scanbot SDK is opensource for you to be able to fix it yourself.