# iOs App rejected by Apple - not getting the packages that uses UIWebview while using 'grep -r UIWebView'

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am writing the full story, main issue is mentioned in the end.

Mail from Apple:
[image]

Link I have followed to fix this issue:[Doc used to fix the issue](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/uiwebview-deprecation-xamarin-forms/)

ios build page:
[image]

Visual studi version:
[image]

**Xamarin iOs versions:**

[image]

xamarin.forms version:4.6.0.1180

Webview Integration:
I am using 'webview' in my Xamarin.forms project which is common for android and ios.
[image]

I have done a search by using the keyword: 'UIWebview', but I couldn't find any such usage in my project.

And then I have added **--warn-on-type-ref=UIKit.UIWebView** in mtouch argument.
Warning log received in the build:
[image]

**And then I was trying with grep -r UIWebView.**
I am not sure whether this is the right way to write the command in terminal. Help me if I am doing wrong. _/_

[image]

I am waiting for a long time.Why it's showing recursive search of stdin??How can I find out the packages which is using UIWebview in xamarin?

Can anyone help me to jump out of this issue .
What may be the mistake I have done here ??????

Thnx in advance :)

Comment: You're only passing two arguments to grep. Change the invocation to be `grep -r UIWebView ./Users/...` (note the space between `UIWebView` and the path)

Comment: are you using xamarin.material package?

Comment: @Anand No,I am not using xamarin.material package.

Comment: @Gereon so you are saying me to add space between the UIWebview and the path?

Comment: @Gereon I am getting "No such file or directory" error if I am adding a spce.I have tried with "grep -r UIWebView. /Users/admin/Documents/kn/hybrid/“Test”/QDH/“40\sep\1”/“teste_Vdeo\2\2\2\2\3”/test_xamarin" and  "grep -r UIWebView ./Users/admin/Documents/kn/hybrid/“Test”/QDH/“40\sep\1”/“teste_Vdeo\2\2\2\2\3”/test_xamarin".But geting the same error.

Comment: Are you using a third-party library with a reference to UIWebView? Update to a version without it or removed altogether from the app.

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT We are having number of naughet packages in the project.I have rescently updated all the packages including the xamarin.Forms version. Here I just want to find out which all are the packages/libraries thar are still using UIWebview.That,s why I am using grep -r UIWebView. in terminal. I am not sure whether the terminal code I have written is in correct format.Can you please help me in that way??

Comment: Hi can you follow the second method in this article. The command you using have slight mistake  https://medium.com/@getSEEC/dev-talk-xamarin-forms-uiwebview-deprecation-and-app-store-rejection-itms-90809-5fe57b885ae2

Comment: @Anand tried that,bt couldnt find any libraries.From the image(error log) i have added in the question.its saying i am using a library named PullToRefresh.Ihave deleted that library ad its a depricated one.Then One more is there:Xamarin.Forms.platform.ios but I am not geting which library is this.

Comment: Can you please refer the answers in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63816259/unable-to-resolve-deprecation-of-uiwebview-warning-while-uploading-xamarin-appli), it's similar to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the issue. There is a change in the way which I have tried 'grep -r UIWebView'

So for all the devprs who all are facing the same issue. I am posting the way in which I solved my issue.

Delete bin and obj folders

Assuming your project path is `User/documents/xamarin/myproject`

Then add

```
cd documents
cd xamarin
```

then write

```
grep -lr "UIWebView"
```

and then return(mac)

You will receive an output that contains all the libraries that using UIWebview.

Main issue will be the Hockeyapp sdk.You should replace it with app center. Delete or update the other libraries which are having UIWebview reference.

And if you are getting sqlite3, just ignore it.

Create archive file. Upload to app store.
:)

Comment: You can mark this answer later which will help more people with same problem:).