# Xamarin ios Rejection-due to the UIWebview in Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.What package is this?

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

[image]

I have received this warning after adding **--warn-on-type-ref=UIKit.UIWebView** in mtouch arguments.
And I could understand there is a nuget package named 'refractored.XamForms.PullToRefresh' in my project.I have removed that nuget package from my project and now the only warning which I am receiving is

[image: current error]
so can anyone help me to find out the package: '**Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOs**'.
I am not having such a package in my project.

Application will be rejected by Apple If I  upload this application with this error.

Comment: That's the iOS platform itself for Xamarin, make sure you do not have any reference in your code to UIWebView, make sure to also update your Xamarin and make sure all your packages are up to date if any one of them for some reason uses a UIWebView

Comment: Remove any reference to `UIWebView`, if you're using any custom renderer that implements a `WebView` change to use the `WKWebViewRenderer`, also update XF to 4.6 or upper and follow [this](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/uiwebview-deprecation-xamarin-forms/) guide to add the experimental feature tag to remove all the `UIWebView` packages from XF

Comment: @SomeStudent I don't have a UIWebview reference in my project. (I have done a search by using ctrl+F).

Comment: @FabriBertani I am using xamarin forms version 4.6.0.1180.I have checked the document that you have mentioned but we can't find a solution for the reported issue from that document.

Comment: Please don't ask duplicate question as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63868717/ios-app-rejected-by-apple-not-getting-the-packages-that-uses-uiwebview-while-u).